# sliding not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need the navigation tab on the left side to slide down its contents on hover. But the code is not working. What might be the problem.

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
    <li  id = "mousehover">
       <a style="background-color:#f78144; color: #000; text-align: center;" href="#">Time  Table</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id = "hovercontent">
    Contents 1 
  </div>



<script type = "script/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#mousehover").hover(function(){
        $("#hovercontent").slideDown("slow");
     });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
<script type="script/javascript">
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

or just use

```
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#mousehover").hover(function(){
        $("#hovercontent").slideDown("slow");
     });
  });
</script>
```

replace script/javascript by text/javascript